# stacking divs with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code which vertically centers my content

html

```
<div class="titleHide flex">
   <h4>...</h4>
   <h1>...</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
.titleHide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(209,30,93,0.8);
}

.flex {
display: flex;
flex: 1;
align-items: center;
}
```

.flex is used by other divs on my site. However in this case it puts the h1 and h4 titles aligned beside each other, I want them the stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may consider writing a separate CSS class for that, say:

```
.flex-stack {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.flex,
.flex-stack {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-stack {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.module-1,
.module-2 {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flex Inline</h3>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="module-1">
    Module #1
  </div>
  <div class="module-2">
    Module #2
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Flex Stacked</h3>

<div class="flex-stack">
  <div class="module-1">
    Module #1
  </div>
  <div class="module-2">
    Module #2
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it was helpful. Cheers!